# Iterable dataset exhausts after a single epoch [IMBD dataset from torchtext]

Tags: python, iterator, pytorch, torchtext

I wanted to train an RNN on the task of sentiment analysis, for this task I was using the IMDB dataset provided by torchtext which contains 50000 movie reviews and it is a python iterator. I used a `split=('train', 'test')`.

I first built a vocab using `torchtext.vocab.Vocab` and tokenized each of the sentence and then performed numericalisation.

To pad the sequence to the same length I used `torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence` and also used a `collate_fn` together with `batch_sampler`. Then I loaded the data using torch.utils.data.`DataLoader`.

The implementation of the RNN Network is fine but the dataloader is exhausted after a single epoch as you can see in the image attached below.

Am I following the right approach to load this iterable-dataset? and why is the dataloader exhausted after a single epoch and how do I overcome this issue.

Pleases refer to the shared colab notebook if you want to see my implementation.

PS. I was following the official [changelog](https://github.com/pytorch/text/blob/master/examples/legacy_tutorial/migration_tutorial.ipynb) of torchtext from github

You can find my implementation [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Ep0s2D2d7fNhhUrYgPTtd5A74FPKsytg?usp=sharing)

[image: Dataloader exhausted after a single epoch]

In the attached image you can see that the dataloader is exhausted after a single epoch.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your dataloader is a generator and it exhausted after fully iterated. One solution is initialize dataloader in each epoch. Second, is do not use batch sampler. Collate function should do what you wanted to do.

```
def collate_batch(batch):
    batch.sort(key=lambda x: len(x[0]), reverse=True)
    label_list, text_list, text_lengths = [], [], []
    
    for _text, _label in batch:
        label_list.append(_label)
        processed_text = torch.tensor(_text)
        text_list.append(processed_text)
        text_lengths.append(len(processed_text))

    return torch.tensor(label_list, dtype=torch.float32),
           pad_sequence(text_list, padding_value=3.0), 
           torch.tensor(text_lengths, dtype=torch.int64)
```